# plotting missing values with nan

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert, plot, nan

I have a plot which looks like this

```
hours = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 12 13 14 15];
y = [0 1 2 nan 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
figure(1)
plot(hours, y, '-o');
```

[image]

As you can see, the x axis jumps from 6 to 12. Instead of having a straight line connecting these points, I would like to have a gap:

```
hours = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15];
y = [0 1 2 nan 3 4 5 nan nan nan nan nan 6 7 8 9];
figure(2)
plot(hours, y, '-o');
```

[image]

Can this be done in an elegant way without having to manually insert the nans and the new 'hours' values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
hours_new = min(hours):max(hours)
nan_ind = ~ismember(hours_new,hours)
y_new(~nan_ind) = y
y_new(nan_ind) = NaN
```

Then, plot like this -

```
figure(2)
plot(hours_new, y_new, '-o');
```